# How to return Realm list in Swift?

Tags: swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I have 2 Realm List

and I'm trying to make healper function 
so I can choose between them to display one of them on UITableview

my model looks like this

```
public class RealmModel : Object {

    public var arrayList1 = List<realmList1>()
    public var arrayList2 = List<realmList2>()


    func ChooseList<T> (cehck : Bool) ->  List<T> {

        if cehck == true {
            return arrayList1 as! List<T>
        } else if cehck == false {
            return arrayList2 as! List<T>

        }
        return arrayList1 as! List<T>
    }


}
```

I'm trying using Generic Type 
but with no luck

when I try to use the function **ChooseList** I got error

```
Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred
```

I don't know how to do it , and if there is another way to archive what i'm trying to archive

Comment: It's a little unclear as to what exactly you are trying to do but you may want to reconsider the design. As it is, the 'main' RealmModel has two lists of Realm objects that are publicly accessible and at the same time there's a function the also returns one of the two arrays; essentially duplicate functionality. Once you've retrieved your RealmModel object from Realm, the arrays could be accessed directly; let someArray = aRealmModel.arrayList1. So expanding on that, arrayList1 or arrayList2 could be used as the tableView dataSource. Can you clarify why you want to use <T> / Generic Type?

Comment: The idea is I don't want to duplicate my code ! , Right now I do duplicate my code exactly as you mention !

Both list will display on same Tableview , so I need to switch between them depend of action the user will use, that why I need to check first so I can display correct content.

I think it's clear now why I need to do it this way

Comment: BTW I did use Generic Type just because I was thinking it's the right thing to use , that mean , I was just trying things .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll suggest an alternative solution. This is macOS but very similar to iOS and it's really just to provide another option.

Suppose we have a tableView and want to switch what's listed in the tableView depending on what the user selects.

Give two Realm objects RedGrape, WhiteGrape

and then a class that contains lists of both of those called Grape. This is similar to what's in the original question but I wanted to use a more well defined item for use in our lists.

```
class RedGrape: Object {
    @objc dynamic var grapeName = ""
}

class WhiteGrape: Object {
    @objc dynamic var grapeName = ""
}

class Grape: Object {
    let reds = List<RedGrape>()
    let whites = List<WhiteGrape>()
}
```

and then a class that handles the tableView within a viewController, note this is just conceptual:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: NSTableView!

    var self.userSelection = 0 //changed by user: 0 for red, 1 for white
    var myGrape = //set up the Grape Object var from Realm

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.userSelection = 0

        self.myTableView.delegate = self
        self.myTableView.dataSource = self

        self.myTableView.reloadData()
    }


    func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        if self.userSelection == 0 {
            return self.myGrape.reds.count
        } else {
            return self.myGrape.white.count 
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, 
                   viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?,
                   row: Int) -> NSView? {
        var name = ""
        if self.userSelection == 0 {
            name = self.myGrape.reds[row].grapeName
        } else {
            name = self.myGrape.whites[row].grapeName
        }

        let cellIdentifier = NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue:"MyCellView")

        if let cellView = self.myTableView.makeView(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, 
                                                 owner: nil) as? NSTableCellView {
            cellView.textField?.stringValue = name
            return cellView
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

from here you could implement more decision making code within the Grape class:

```
class Grape: Object {
    let reds = List<RedGrape>()
    let whites = List<WhiteGrape>()

    func rowCountFor(selection: Int) -> Int {
      if selection == 0 {
         return self.Grape.reds.count
      } else {
         return self.Grape.white.count 
      }

    func nameFor(selection: Int, forRow: Int) -> String {
       if selection == 0 {
         return self.reds[forRow]
      } else {
         return self.whites[forRow]
      }
    }
}
```

then your tableView numberOfRows becomes

```
    func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        self.myGrape.rowCountFor(selection: self.userSelection)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case,arrayList1 is SomeOtherType. 
List is not that type, with the as! cast is dangerous.Always Use as?

Try this one,

```
public var arrayList1 : DataType = List<realmList1>()
public var arrayList2 : DataType = List<realmList2>()


func ChooseList<T> (cehck : Bool) ->  List<T>? {

    if cehck == true {
        return arrayList1 as? List<T>
    } else if cehck == false {
        return arrayList2 as? List<T>

    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont think that you need generics here if your realmList1 and realmList2 are inherited from Object you can write your chooseList method like this

```
    func ChooseList(cehck : Bool) ->  List<Object> {

    if cehck == true {
        return arrayList1 as! List<realmList1> // or just return arrayList1
    } else if cehck == false {
        return arrayList2 as! List<realmList2> // or just return arrayList2

    }
    return arrayList1 as! List<realmList1>
}
```

Comment: This was the frist thing I tried 

I got error :

Cannot convert return expression of type 'List<realmList1>' to return type 'List<Object>'